# How to hide/remove "box" with comments and "Share on facebook" information?

Tags: css, facebook

How to hide/remove "box" with comments and "Share on facebook" information?(It is displayed after click "Like")

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0):

When I have this issue/need I simply add a width to the element containing the iframe(like button), I believe it is somewhere around 80px.